# When i click into text it works but when i click beside text it doesn't work in dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have made my own drop down menu but problem is when i click in text it links to other place successfully but when i click beside text it doesn't link to other place, can you please help me what's wrong here?? help would be appreciated!!

here is my pic:

[image]

and here is my source code for `drop-down` menu..

```
<style>
    ul {
        text-align: left;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
        list-style: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        box-shadow:         0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    }
    ul li {
        font: bold 12px/18px Throw My Hands Up in the Air;
        font-size: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: -4px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        background: #D00000;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    ul li:hover {
        background: #555;
        color: #fff;
    }
    ul li ul {
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 48px;
        left: 0;
        width: 150px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }
    ul li ul li {
        background: #555;
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    }
    ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
    ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #header{
        background-color: #D00000;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        right: 0%;
        height: 8%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        box-shadow:         0px 3px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    }

    #left_box{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        position: fixed;
        width: 20%;
        top: 10%;
        left: 0%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    a{
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .box
    {
        width: 80%;
        padding:10px;
        border:2px solid gray;
        position: fixed;
        top: 12%;
        left: 15%;
        height: 50%;
    }

</style>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <ul><li><a href="home.php" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">Home</a></li>
        <li>Notification</li>
        <li>
            Profile
            <ul>
                <li>All members</li>
                <li><a href="profile.php" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff">My profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Settings
            <ul>
                <li><a href="setting.php" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff">Logout</a></li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The a tag is an inline element, so by default it's only the width of the text.  Add display: block; to the link to make it 100% width:

```
ul li a { display: block; }
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the only the text is considered the actual "link", because it's the innerHTML of the `<a>` tag.  You may have to alter the CSS a little, but try wrapping the `<li>` tag in the `<a>` tag so you get `<a href="link"><li>Link Name</a>`.  Then clicking anywhere on the `<li>` element should activate the link.

Comment: Yeah as Helpful says, this option isn't very clean. I would avoid doing this option as technically you have invalid html there and will probably cause unexpected results in other browsers. My example below is the standard css used in the vast majority of cases for dropdown menus.

Comment: I don't think this is 'invalid html,' and display:block seems more likely to cause css/display issues in various browsers.  This works, it's just not elegant - multiple changes vs 1 change.

Comment: Actually if you run this through the w3c validator for any doctype, it is very much invalid html.  An 'li' must be directly within a 'ul' or 'ol'.  Putting it within an 'a' tag is malformed, which particularly for ie can cause it to not trust the output and default to a quirks mode or compatibility mode rendering model.  An 'a' with display:block within an li that's also display: block is the standard convention for menu building.

Comment: I didn't check the validator, suppose I ought to have.  Well, I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bad form to put anything besides inline elements in anchor tag.
Easiest solution?

Specify a width for all your menu dropdown elements as they are the same width already..

```
#header li > ul > li > a { width: 125px; }
```

should make all nested dropdowns same width.

Ensure you have

```
 a { display: block; }
```

as well...